# Extra Title field for Comments

Tags: comments

I want to display an extra title field for comments, that can be edited by the admin in the backend. NB, The extra title field also needs to display when the user is logged in. I have tried a range of plugins with no success. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can save your title as an option (as a theme option, plugin option) and output it when you need in your templates

check the [Option API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

you can use:
`<?php if( is_user_logged_in()  ) : ?>` to output only for user actually logged in